# How to get value of argument in Build Process Template

Tags: c#, tfs, build, build-process

I'm writting the customized build process template and facing as below issue related to the value of input argument. Please help.

1. Cloned the StandardTemplate.xml and renamed to CustomTemplate.xml
2. Add new argument named BatFileLocation
3. Try to display the value of argument of BatFileLocation as below code

   // Define an activity input argument of type string

   ```
   public InArgument<string> BatFileLocation { set; get; }

   protected override void Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
   {
       // Obtain the runtime value of the Text input argument
       string text = context.GetValue(this.BatFileLocation);
       context.TrackBuildWarning(string.Format("Trigger the {0}", text));
   }
   ```

But the result is EMPTY or NULL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue has been resolved by remapping again the VARIABLE of template & input arguments of Customer activities.

Steps are as below:
- Righ click on Custom Activities just added into template
- Mapping the input arguments of Custom Activities with VARIABLE declared in template